# Not able to update ubuntu 12.10

Tags: updates

While updating my ubuntu 12.10 am getting the following error.
Could anyone help!

```
W:Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 74.125.31.91 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 74.125.31.91 80]
```

Comment: Are you using any internet proxy like squid?